# adding view controller as child view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Hi i am trying to add a `view controller` as a `child view`. and later remove this `view controller` form parent view.I am using following code for this purpose.

```
 self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
 [self.view addSubview:self.loginView.view];
```

This code works fine for `iOS8` but in `iOS7` this code is not working it shows the half of the screen.On half part login is shown.

What could be the solution for this??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a custom `UIView` object in your main view (in XIB) in which you want to add and show your child view controller. Let `contentView` is the name of that view. Use following code to add child view controller:

```
self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
[self addChildViewController:self.loginView];
[self.loginView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.loginView.view];
[self.loginView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

if you don't add last line, your child view controller will not receive events. By using this code you can simultaneously receive events in both parent and child view controllers.

Comment: I have a question for you guys.
how can I pass a data (string or int) to child view before or after loading the childView. Thank you..

Comment: I don't really understand why you edit the post, this code is unreadable.
You are calling a UIViewController view, it make the code very confusing.
I hope you are not coding like this in real life.

Comment: I had used the name same as what was mentioned in question. I never use these naming convention in real life.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `UIViewController` as a `subView` is not standard programming I believe, `UIViewController` is intended to handle a complete view on screen. Instead of adding a `UIViewController` to your `UIView` you should create a custom `UIView` and then use that `UIView` to achieve whatever results you want to.

EDIT : Use XIB to create a custom UIView.

Comment: I have designed the view from story board so that i why i am adding a view controller as subview

Comment: Yes but you can create custom Views in Xibs in the same way you did for Storyboards. You just have to assign a UIView class to the xib and then create an instance of that class.