# Add child view controller to current view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to add a child view controller in code, to the current view controller from storyboard by using the next code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
LogInTutorialViewController *lvc = [[LogInTutorialViewController alloc] init];
lvc = (LogInTutorialViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogInTutorialViewControllerID"];
[self displayContentController:lvc];

- (void) displayContentController: (LogInTutorialViewController*) content;
{

    //add as childViewController
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [content.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];

}
```

The view seem to be displaying on the simulator at least but in console I get a lot or error:

```
 <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

And also the same description but different error:

CGContextSetLineWidth, CGContextSetLineJoin, CGContextSetLineCap, CGContextSetMiterLimit, CGContextSetFlatness, CGContextAddPath, CGContextDrawPath, CGContextRestoreGState

all these error get logged twice.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

also I read a few posts and in some it was suggested to alloc and init the view controller before passing the data, I also tried that without any luck.

Comment: You don't need this line `LogInTutorialViewController *lvc = [[LogInTutorialViewController alloc] init];` ,since you are instantiating from story board. For the errors check below answers, your order is not correct I believe.

Comment: yes, i know but I just tried it as a post suggested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

didMoveToParentViewController must be the last.

Comment: all the errors get logged when I get to the line:  [content.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

Comment: Try to add subview first and then set it frame.

Comment: Now I suspect you problem is related to what inside your child view controller view, not to parent-child relation.

Comment: tried the next code:     [self addChildViewController:content];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [content.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)]; And I still get the error logged now on the didMoveToParent line

Comment: What does LogInTutorialViewController view have inside? Looks like it has some drawings problem.

Comment: a few uiimageviews, uitextfields amd uibuttons

Answer (score 29):

why you do not try this code for adding view i think this one is simple and easy..

```
self.loginView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
[self addChildViewController:self.loginView];
[self.loginView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.loginView.view];
[self.loginView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

for further more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222383/adding-view-controller-as-child-view-in-ios).

Comment: The part that was throwing me off was having to explicitly set the origin to zero. This `[self.loginView.view setFrame:self.contentView.frame]` wouldn't set it properly within the view for me as my `contentView` had a `UINavigationBar` so `contentView.frame.origin.y` was 64 thus pushed `self.loginView` down. Thanks!

Comment: this answer has 15+ up votes and accepted answer has 13 up votes. so i think this answer must be a accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

**Solution in Swift** (Swift 4 at the time of this writing):

```
//load the view controller and add as child
storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LOGIN")
addChildViewController(loginVC)

//make sure that the child view controller's view is the right size
loginVC.view.frame = contentView.bounds
contentView.addSubview(loginVC.view)

//you must call this at the end per Apple's documentation
loginVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Notes:

- Storyboard name is "Main".
- View controller identifier in the storyboard is named "LOGIN".
- This uses a storyboard to create load the view controller, but the same can be done programmatically. Just make sure the view is loaded into memory before you try and access the view's frame or you will get a crash (do something like present the view controller modally).

Comment: Thank you, this solution works like a charm in swift 4

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an extension for adding and removing `UIViewController`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addChildViewControllerWithView(_ childViewController: UIViewController, toView view: UIView? = nil) {
        let view: UIView = view ?? self.view
        childViewController.removeFromParent()
        childViewController.willMove(toParent: self)
        addChild(childViewController)
        childViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        view.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: childViewController.view!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: childViewController.view!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: childViewController.view!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: childViewController.view!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ])
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func removeChildViewController(_ childViewController: UIViewController) {
        childViewController.removeFromParent()
        childViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        childViewController.removeFromParent()
        childViewController.didMove(toParent: nil)
        childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Whenever you'd like to add `UIViewController` in the `viewDidLoad()` method you need to call `addChildViewControllerWithView(someVC)`