# Put an object in front of every others after a tap on it

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uitapgesturerecognizer

So, i've got a personalized object (PostIt.xib).
I've got a function : addNewPostIt that when i press the good button... Yeah you got it (hint: it add a new postit ;) ).

So i'm able to create a lot of them by pressing the button, and every postit is draggable (thanks to pan gesture recognizer).

Now, what i want to do is, when i tap on one of them, it will put it in front of every of all the others.

I think i should use a Tap Gesture Recognizer obviously but i dont know how to process... 
Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: i've got a UITapGestureRecognizer which is linked in my PostIt.h under :

Here is my addNewPostIt function if you want to have a look:

```
- (IBAction)addNewPostIt:(id)sender {
    PostIt *postit = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostIt" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    postit.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 400, 400);
    [self.view addSubview:postit];
    x+=50;
    y+=50;
}

-(IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok try this,

```
- (IBAction)addNewPostIt:(id)sender {
   PostIt *postit = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostIt" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
  postit.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 400, 400);
  [self addTapGestureTo:postit];
  [self.view addSubview:postit];
  x+=50;
  y+=50;

}

- (void)addTapGestureTo:(PostIt *)postit
{
   UITapGestureRecognizer *aTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedPostIt:)];
   [postit addGestureRecognizer:aTapGesture];
}

- (void)tappedPostIt:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
  UIView *targetView = tapGesture.view;
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:targetView];
}
```

if u want `tap:` method in PostIt.h file then u can do like below

in `PostIt.m` file u need to handle the tap like below,
super view holds all the `PostIt` view's that u are added, so u must call the superview's `bringSubviewToFront` method

```
- (IBAction)tap:(id)sender {
  [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
```

Comment: I think I must use [self bringSubviewToFront:targetView]; Then, it didn't work but i want to add that my UITapGestureRecognizer is linked in my PostIt.h with: -(IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
Perhaps it could help you to help me :p (I'll add this in my question for more clarity)

Comment: ok the add the code to handle tap  in `-(IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recogniser`

Comment: I dont really understand what you are saying here... Where do I need to add this line in my code? This line is exactly the same that I already have in my PostIt.h. Explain me a bit more please :) @Shan

Comment: Yes it is working! I just wanted to add that I had to do this: in Sent Actions, i've linked tap: with PostIt and in Referencing Outlet Collections I've linked gestureRecognizers with PostIt.

Again thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want that view on top of all view then you have to use this

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.postit.view];
```

and also see this link to add subview

[Add child view controller to current view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller)