# How to load multiple xib files to single view in view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, view

I'm developing a quiz iOS application. There are 5 types of questions in quiz like **Answer_Image** (question is text and 4 objective images), **Question_image** (question is image and 4 text fields) etc.

So I want to change **view according to question type** in run time.

Comment: you can do it like this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller