# iOS 10, QLPreviewViewController is not displaying files

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I am working on a iOS app that displays lots of different files to the user.  From video and audio files to html and Office/iWorks files.  I have subclassed QLPreviewController, and want to use it to display some of these files.  I create the object, pass it the file's url, set the ViewController's view's frame to replace the webView's frame in the parent viewcontroller. :

```
else if (QuickLookViewController.canOpenFile(previewItem: contentUrl as NSURL)) {

    hideControls()
    quickLook.contentURLs = [contentUrl as NSURL]

    //add the QuickLookController's view to content display using webview's frame
    self.view.addSubview(quickLook.view)

    quickLook.view.frame = webview!.frame
    quickLook.reloadData()
```

Using the view debug hierarchy tool, it shows the view set correctly,  as well as setting quickLook.backgroundColor = UIColor.black just to test.

So I thought that maybe there was a problem with accessing the download and stored file, so in the viewDidLoad of QuickLookController I added some tests to ensure that the file is there:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
print("\nContent URL: \(contentURLs[0])")
print("\nContent URL Path: \(contentURLs[0].path!)")

self.delegate = self
self.dataSource = self
var error : NSError?

print("\nis reachable: \(contentURLs[0].checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error))")
if (error != nil) {
    print("is reachable error -> \(error.debugDescription)")
}
print("\ndoes exist: \(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: contentURLs[0].path!))")
print("\nCan open: \(QuickLookViewController.canOpenFile(previewItem: contentURLs[0]))")
```

and the log statements come out as I expect:

```
Content URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B9D5C288-F889-4513-941E-2564F1C12F02/Documents/588c5a1e-dffe-47a8-9824-bc19463aafc2/d88a8dd5-40d1-4fdb-adf3-10fce1f6bf1f/fd73c162-5ac3-4269-8573-9c0b61bef7a7/fd73c162-5ac3-4269-8573-9c0b61bef7a7.pages

Content URL Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B9D5C288-F889-4513-941E-2564F1C12F02/Documents/588c5a1e-dffe-47a8-9824-bc19463aafc2/d88a8dd5-40d1-4fdb-adf3-10fce1f6bf1f/fd73c162-5ac3-4269-8573-9c0b61bef7a7/fd73c162-5ac3-4269-8573-9c0b61bef7a7.pages

is reachable: true

does exist: true

Can open: true
```

I even used a breakpoint in the the viewDidLoad to check that the quickLook's superview is set using 'po self.view.superview!.frame' as a llbd statement, and again received the output I expected.

I used this same class for another view stack in the app and it displays the files that are clicked, so it isn't making much sense to me.  The only difference between the two uses, the second I am presenting the quickLook's view in a viewController that is presented modally.

Answer (score 0):

ok I wanted to post the answer to the problem I was having.  The issue was I was not adding the quickLook view controller to the ContentDisplayViewController with a parent-child relationship.  So the updated code to add the view I wanted looks like:

```
//create the parent-child relationship for the view controllers
self.addChildViewController(quickLook)

//give the view it's frame
quickLook.view.frame = webview!.frame

//add the view and call the child's didMove() method.
self.view.addSubview(quickLook.view)
quickLook.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

This question gave me the answer:
[Add child view controller to current view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller)

Gave me me some reading material to read into, thanks for the post @Piyush Patel