# ContainerView in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I  am new to ios and working on container view first time.I have a containerview in a `Taskviewcontrolle`r .The containerview contains four childs i.e. Viewcontroller A,Viewcontroller B,Viewcontroller C,Viewcontroller D.

These Viewcontrollers contains table view cells .When I click on the cells of **ViewcontrollerA** it opens `AdetailViewcontroller`,When I click on the cells of **ViewcontrollerB** it opens `BdetailViewcontroller`,When I click on the cells of **ViewcontrollerC** it opens `CdetailViewcontroller`,When I click on the cells of **ViewcontrollerD** it opens `DdetailViewcontroller`.

These View controllers have back
(Task) button (that comes by default due to navigation).This button is suppose to take to the previous Viewcontroller,like if it is on `CdetailViewcontroller`,then it should bring back to `CViewcontroller`).But this doesn't happen actually .In every case ,it brings back to `ViewcontrollerA`.I am not able to understand the reason.

Please help to fix this.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: All view controllers are in storyboard only?

Comment: yes ,they all are in storyboard

Comment: share some code if you have done anything programmatically.

Comment: Sir, i have done nothing programatically..just used segues for the connections

Answer (score 0):

As your all view controller A, B, C, D are child view controller of task view controller and when you are navigating the navigation controller of task view controller is used as it is the parent of all four controllers.

So when you do popviewcontroller it goes back to task view controller(not to any child view controller specifically). And when task view controller is appearing it reinitialises all its child view controller which sets view controller A as default child of its container view.

If you want your desired result, add the child view controllers from code in viewDidLoad of TaskViewController.

Visit [Add child view controller to current view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller)

Comment: How this can be changed,as I want it to return to the same child from where this came actually.

Comment: See the answer in the link to add child view controller programatically. After that implement those in your viewDidLoad, if that does not do the desired result, feel free to comment.