# how to present modal UIViewController dialog from bottom in IOS like this (image attached)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller

How would one present a UIViewController (from Storyboard say) that is modal, and slides up from the bottom of the presenting view controller.  Requirements would be:

- slides up from bottom, with widths aligning with the width of the presenting view controller
- does NOT take up whole screen or whole parent presenting view controller (rather only is as high as required to show itself)
- can be shown within the context of a view controller which doesn't take the whole screen

[image]

Comment: Hi Greg, were u able to achieve the result with Swift. It would be helpful if you paste a snippet as I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use storyboards so I wrote it all out. You can copy paste this into a brand new project and run it to see it working.

Your PresentingController needs to conform to two things. The first protocol is: `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` which allows the controller to provide a custom presenter (namely itself in our case below). Whatever you return here (be it self, or some other object) needs to conform to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and provide the custom animations. For this self-contained example, I chose the current viewController to be the presenter and animator.

Next, it needs to conform to protocol: `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` which provides the custom animation for any presenting or dismissing controllers.

In other words, when we present or dismiss a viewController, `animateTransition` from the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol will be called to determine how the child controller should animate into perspective or dismiss from the view-port.

Example (With Transition Animation):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  SO
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2017-01-23.
//  Copyright © 2017 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


//Some view controller that will be presented modally.
//I have coloured it red.
@interface ModalController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation ModalController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
@end



//The view controller that will present or dismiss some other view controller modally.
//I have coloured it white.
@interface ViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>
@property (nonatomic, assign) bool presentingModalController;
@property (nonnull, nonatomic, strong) ModalController *modalController;
@property (nonnull, nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //For this example, I add a button to present and dismiss the redViewController.
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, self.view.center.y - 100, self.view.frame.size.width - 30, 45)];
    [self.button setTitle:@"Present" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];


    //Create the redViewController and set its transitioning delegate to self (this controller will be providing the animation and presenter).
    //We also set the style to OverFullScreen because we don't want this controller to disappear.
    //When a view controller is presented, the one that presented it usually disappears or gets removed from the hierarchy until the child is dismissed. In the case of alerts, or controllers that need to display OVER the current one, we need to set the modalPresentationStyle.
    self.modalController = [[ModalController alloc] init];
    self.modalController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    self.modalController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)onButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    if (self.modalController.view.window == nil) {
        [self presentViewController:self.modalController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.button setTitle:@"Dismiss" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //not a good idea but meh.. I need to keep this example short.
        [self.view.window addSubview:self.button];
    }
    else {
        [self.modalController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.button setTitle:@"Present" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:self.button];
    }
}


//Custom Animations and Presenters.
- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    self.presentingModalController = true; //We are presenting the controller.
    return self; //Who is animating it? We are.
}

- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    self.presentingModalController = false; //We are dismissing the view controller.
    return self; //Who animated it? We did.
}

//How fast should it present? I chose 0.5 seconds.
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(nullable id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.5;
}

//The actual animation code.
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    if (self.presentingModalController) { 
        //If we are presenting, we need to add the new controller's view as a sub-view.

        UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

        //We need a starting frame for the animation.
        CGRect startingFrame = transitionContext.containerView.bounds;
        startingFrame.origin.y = startingFrame.size.height; //Starts from the bottom of the parent.
        startingFrame.size.height = 100; //Has a height of 100.

        //We need an end frame for the animation.
        CGRect finalFrame = transitionContext.containerView.bounds;
        finalFrame.origin.y = finalFrame.size.height - 100; //100 from the bottom of the parent.
        finalFrame.size.height = 100; //Present with a size of 100 height.

        //Add the controller's view as a subview of the context.
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
        [toViewController.view setFrame:startingFrame];

        //Start animating from "startFrame" --> "endFrame" with 0.5 seconds duration and no delay. I chose easeIn style.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            [toViewController.view setFrame:finalFrame];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //We are finished animating, complete the transition!
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    }
    else {
        //If we are dismissing the view controller, we need to animate it down the screen and then remove its view from the context.

        UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

        //We only need one frame. This is the first frame. We are animating from "endFrame" --> "startingFrame" (backwards/reverse animation).
        CGRect startingFrame = transitionContext.containerView.bounds;
        startingFrame.origin.y = startingFrame.size.height; //Starts from the bottom of the parent.
        startingFrame.size.height = 100; //Has a height of 100.


        //Start the animation with 0.5 seconds duration and I chose easeOut style.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [fromViewController.view setFrame:startingFrame];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            //Remove the view controller's view from the context and complete the transition!
            [fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

---

Example (Without Transition Animation):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  SO2
//
//  Created by Brandon Thomas on 2017-01-23.
//  Copyright © 2017 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ModalController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation ModalController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
@end



@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) bool presentingModalController;
@property (nonnull, nonatomic, strong) ModalController *modalController;
@property (nonnull, nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, self.view.center.y - 100, self.view.frame.size.width - 30, 45)];
    [self.button setTitle:@"Present" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];


    self.modalController = [[ModalController alloc] init];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)onButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    if (self.modalController.view.window == nil) {
        //Present
        CGRect startingFrame = self.view.bounds;
        startingFrame.origin.y = startingFrame.size.height; //Starts from the bottom of the parent.
        startingFrame.size.height = 100; //Has a height of 100.

        CGRect finalFrame = self.view.bounds;
        finalFrame.origin.y = finalFrame.size.height - 100; //100 from the bottom of the parent.
        finalFrame.size.height = 100; //Present with a size of 100 height.

        [self.modalController.view setFrame:startingFrame];

        [self.modalController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self addChildViewController:self.modalController];
        [self.view addSubview:self.modalController.view];
        [self.modalController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [self.modalController.view setFrame:finalFrame];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
    else {
        //Dismiss
        CGRect startingFrame = self.view.bounds;
        startingFrame.origin.y = startingFrame.size.height; //Starts from the bottom of the parent.
        startingFrame.size.height = 100; //Has a height of 100.

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [self.modalController.view setFrame:startingFrame];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.modalController.view removeFromSuperview];
            [self.modalController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [self.modalController removeFromParentViewController];
            [self.modalController didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: looks great and worked...should it work within container views like I showed?  I'll try it out too...

Comment: quick question whilst I test this if I may....If I wasn't concerned at all about the "animation" look & feel, would I still need to use the "UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" approach as a means to get an end result where the modal view controller is shown only on the bottom portion of the parent view controller?     Is there issue here that there is no modalPresentationStyle one could use to achieve this hence you have to use the animation approach?  i.e. no UIModalPresentationStyle.overTheBottomHalfOfTheScreen for example

Comment: There's no such thing. The other option is to size the modal view controller then add its view as a subview without all the animations. That's the only other alternative that I know of.

Comment: ok Brandon thanks - so in reality you want some sort of animation, so given this one needs to use the approach you've given I guess....I'm just porting across to Swift and my test project to testing....thanks again

Comment: @Greg; I have edited the code to add that sample as well. It now uses BOTH presentation styles. The first with animation transition, and the second is just adding it as a ChildController.

Comment: oh...so the 2nd one you've effectively got my requirements working without needing the "UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" approach?

Comment: @Greg; Yes. They both do the same thing. The only difference is that the first one is actually "presented" and the second is a "child controller". They both achieve the same thing in this case. **Note:** The second example will still allow you to present other controllers. The first example will NOT allow that because you've already presented a controller already.

Comment: actually which approach do you like best yourself Brandon here?  (e.g. maybe from a readability / re-usability point of view?)

Comment: @Greg For reusability, the first approach is best. You can create an animator class and add the animation code and everything to it. Then any controller that needs that animation will set its delegate to that animator's instance. For readability, either one. If you refactor the first example into an animator object, it would be more legible than the second example. However, the reader would have to navigate through the controller an animator. The second example you see what it's doing immediately. I usually use the first example for presenting things.

Comment: @Greg if I can't use the first one (Possibly because I need other controllers to be presented) then I always use the second one. The second approach can be done to as many view controllers as you want (you can have many child controllers).

Comment: I see what you mean - thanks again Brandon, I've been struggling trying to get my head around custom presentation / custom animation / existing presentations capability trying to understand how to solve my relatively simple requirement...

Comment: @Greg go with the second example for your case. It's simpler, just as fast, easy to read and understand. I'm sure you can find a way to make it reusable too (IE: refactor the button's logic into an object or category). The first approach is more advanced and isn't "necessary" to accomplish your goal, but it's nice to know for the next time you encounter a similar situation. Both are nice to know :)

Comment: actually did have a similar question but re non-modal which I posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498872/how-to-implement-non-modal-dialog-in-ios-like-this-image-attached

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html) for this:

> **Presenting a View Controller Using Custom Animations**
>
> To present a view controller using custom animations, do the following
>   in an action method of your existing view controllers:
>
> Create the view controller that you want to present. Create your
>   custom transitioning delegate object and assign it to the view
>   controller’s transitioningDelegate property. The methods of your
>   transitioning delegate should create and return your custom animator
>   objects when asked. Call the
>   presentViewController:animated:completion: method to present the view
>   controller. When you call the
>   presentViewController:animated:completion: method, UIKit initiates the
>   presentation process. Presentations start during the next run loop
>   iteration and continue until your custom animator calls the
>   completeTransition: method. Interactive transitions allow you to
>   process touch events while the transition is ongoing, but
>   noninteractive transitions run for the duration specified by the
>   animator object.

EDIT:

Your alternative option is to create a container with your custom sizes and animate your UIViewController added as a child view of your UIViewController:

```
[self addChildViewController:content];
content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
[self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
[content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

[Taken from this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller)

Comment: what about from the "presenting" approach - e.g. popover, modal etc do you think?  I don't need a custom presentation process then? e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningCustomPresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH25-SW1

Comment: @Greg If you use the addChildViewController method, you don't need the custom presentation process and all the complications. You can "simply" create your own subview container and add the viewController as a child, and animate it in as you wish.

Comment: were you thinking to add a "container view" in interface builder, and then use this when you programmatically want to add the child viewcontroller then?  In IB would the "container view" be "on top of" the containing view then (e.g. say it had a map within it), but it would be hidden/nothing in it normally until one programmtically addes the child view controller to it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow , but , basically, create the UIViewController as you wish, either in storyboard or programatically. You don't need to add it to a containerView if you don't want to. Then in your mainViewController you can either call it with "alloc init" or if you create it in storyboard you call it with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. Then you add it as I showed you above. Don't forget to remove it [vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController]; , and don't forget to accept this answer if it helps you :P haha GL

Comment: ok - I'll try it out over the next couple of hours - thanks @sneak .  So I guess you only need the Creating Custom Presentations approach when you need to have it be adaptive, but in my case it's basically the same approach for either compact or regular...

Comment: @Greg Exactly! Easy and no complications.