# how to implement non-modal dialog in IOS like this (image attached)?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, non-modal

Question: How would one best implement **non-modal** dialog in IOS like this (image attached)?  Allow ability to drag move map still and select (long press) another location, which then that detail is populated in the pop-up "non-modal" dialog.  Dialog can have ability to "delete" / "add to favourites" etc.

To clarify:

- I'm asking how to implement the dialogs in the image I have marked "Non Modal Popup"
- so for the iPad/horizontal regular case, I'm highlighting the dialog would be associated with the ViewController on the right, so therefore in this case the user could still drag the map within VC2, but also access/use VC1 as well

Some notes re my pondering:

- can UIViewController.present NOT be used here as it is modal? If it can be used what settings to get this working?
- it not would you recommend using an (a) separate UIViewControllerto implement, and show it up using the manual means of adding a UIViewController, OR (b) is it better to just keep it as a UIView in this case?  In either of these cases one would have to do any adaption programmatically?

[image: non-modal dialog requirements]

Comment: Have three controllers. A master controller (UIViewController) that contains TWO child controllers (A: The left menu controller, and B: The map view controller). Then animate controller A from the left of the screen over controller B.

Comment: Oh sorry, my question was re the non modal pop-up I show