# How to simulate the card click animation on the new Apple Store "Today" feed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

When clicking on any card of the new Apple Store today feed, there's a really nice animation that first gives a sense of depth (card becomes smaller), and after the card expands, completely filling the view.

On the opposite direction, if the user slides his finger down, the view becomes the card again (everything back to normal).

Are there any libraries that do that? I've been trying using `UIView.animate` but my results have been horrible. Could someone give me some directions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: It's a UIViewController Transitioning Interactive presentation animation. Then the underlying animation is either done with `CABasicAnimation` or `UIView.animate`..  Implement `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `animationControllerForPresentedController` See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818084/how-to-present-modal-uiviewcontroller-dialog-from-bottom-in-ios-like-this-image for example.. but instead you'd just morph from one view to the other and springAnimate..

Comment: It is probably done using something like the new peek & pop functionality.  Check this out https://the-nerd.be/2015/10/06/3d-touch-peek-and-pop-tutorial/

Comment: @Brandon, Have you tried Hero? I am trying to do it using Hero but no luck :/