# Switch the sub viewController use segmented control

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I want switch the sub view controller from the segment control.

There is vc1 and vc2 in the storyboard, and there is segment control on the main vc's navigation controller bar.

I want to add the vc1 and vc2 on the main vc, how to switch the sub vc use the segment controller?

[image]

How to do with that?

Comment: in here you need to go for tabbar controller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can  I use the sub view controller to do with that?

Comment: @qg_java Use `Containerview`, check this tutorial on it exactly what you are looking for https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/ Or this one https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps.

1. Add VC1 & VC2 as a childVC of mainVC.
2. On segment 1 selection `VC1.view.hidden = false` & `vc2.view.hidden = true`
3. On segment 2 selection `VC2.view.hidden = false` & `vc1.view.hidden = true`

**take reference**

1. [How-to-add-childVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller)
2. [How-tobind-segment-control-action](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/segmented-control-tutorial-ios10)

**Code work**

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        vc1.view.hidden = false
        vc2.view.hidden = true
    case 1:
        vc2.view.hidden = false
        vc1.view.hidden = true
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more detail abuot that? my friend.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is obviously correct, but I honestly prefer using container view for each tab in UISegmentedControl. It that way the logic related with each view is separated in different view controller. You can achieve this in that way:

[image]

```
class TopViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondContainerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstContainerView.alpha = 1.0
        secondContainerView.alpha = 0.0
    }

    @IBAction func didChangeIndex(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            firstContainerView.alpha = 1.0
            secondContainerView.alpha = 0.0
        case 1:
            firstContainerView.alpha = 0.0
            secondContainerView.alpha = 1.0
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to access properties of FirstViewController or SecondViewController, you can implement `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should add vc, and the vc.view to the Main ViewController:

When you select the Segmented Control, you can hide the sub viewcontroller's view like below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    _vc1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    _vc2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

    [self addChildViewController:_vc1];
    [self addChildViewController:_vc2];
    [self.view addSubview:_vc1.view];
    [self.view addSubview:_vc2.view];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)segAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    if (1 == sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        NSLog(@"1");

        _vc1.view.hidden = YES;
        _vc2.view.hidden = NO;
    }else {
        NSLog(@"%ld", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
        _vc2.view.hidden = YES;
        _vc1.view.hidden = NO;
    }

}
```