# Adding view from another class as presentViewController causes UIEvents not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to build a simple library with working UIElements. What I am trying to do is, creating UIViewController objects from one class instances and push that new ViewController on the current VC Stack with the presentViewController method.

I can see that the UIElements has been successfully adding on the stack, but GestureRecognizer and UIButton's target does not work. When I am checking on ViewDebug, these settings are `<NSNull null>`.

This is my class method which I am creating the UI and putting on the current view stack.

```
-(void)displayAd{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Thread
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullpageCampaign.mainImage]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Run UI Updates
            fullPageView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            fullPageView.view.frame = CurrentVC.view.bounds;
            fullPageView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            UIImageView *staticImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            staticImageView.frame = CurrentVC.view.frame;

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
            singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [staticImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
            staticImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [fullPageView.view addSubview:staticImageView];

            staticImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [CurrentVC.view addSubview:fullPageView.view];
            //[fullPageView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            [CurrentVC presentViewController:fullPageView animated:YES completion:^{
                NSLog(@"Tagon Ads is about to showing.");
                UIButton *closeButton = [self createButtonWithAssetName:@"tagonAssets.bundle/close_button" TargetMethod:@"closeModal" andView:staticImageView];
                [staticImageView addSubview:closeButton];
                [CurrentVC.view bringSubviewToFront:closeButton];
            }];
        });
    });
}
```

CurrentVC is the current viewController that I am sending as a parameter through my library's method in order to add a new viewController stack on to it.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller/32965131#32965131

Comment: Are you really sure that this link is related with my question?

Comment: Try to set CurrentVC.view.clipsToBounds = YES; and if your ui elements disappear that means you set CurrentVC.view.frame incorrectly

Comment: MY UIElements are not disappearing, they just can't be set Target and UIEvents as like a GestureRecognizer, UIButton target and @selectors etc..

Comment: May I ask you why do you present `fullPageView` on `CurrentVC` if you have already added fullPageView's view as subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `closeModal` action? Probably same class as your `currentVC`. If so, your `closeButton` referenced `currentVC` but you already gone to `fullPageView` from there. So, your button lost his reference.

Just create new controller, send `imageData` there, create custom initializer, create new `UIImageView` and `UIButton` in there. With this way, your button gonna be reference own root and your problem should be solved.

Comment: It's solved my question thank you! Creating a new view controller from xcode and allocate it on custom class solved solid :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, but first of all, I would recommend a different approach to accomplish what you want. As you can see below, using an instance of `UIViewController` is not the recommended way. Instead, use a *storyboard* to set up your view controller and it's components. Your code will be much smaller and your design will be easy to understand and change.

[You can read more about UIViewController here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller%20%22Apple's%20documentation%20for%20UIViewController)

> You rarely create instances of the UIViewController class directly.
>   Instead, you create instances of UIViewController subclasses and use
>   those objects to provide the specific behaviors and visual appearances
>   that you need.

Here is another potential. Is `fullpageCampaign.mainImage` residing remotely or locally? If remotely located, then you should consider changing to `NSURLSession` instead.

[Read more about NSData:dataWithContentsOfURL here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl)

> Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For
>   network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens
>   of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and
>   in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

Another minor thing is that you add the button to the image view. While this is OK, and might work when you allow user interaction for the image view, a cleaner way to do it is to create a UIView container to hold the image view and the button. The container can then also be the view that you attach the tap gesture recognizer to. That way, the image view can stay as a pure image.

### The storyboard approach

First, create a sub-class of UIIViewController. It should look something like this:

*FullPageViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FullPageViewController : UIViewController

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)adImage;

@end
```

*FullPageViewController.m*

```
#import "FullPageViewController.h"

@interface FullPageViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *adImageView;

@end

@implementation FullPageViewController

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)adImage {
    self.adImageView.image = adImage;
}

- (IBAction)tappedOnAd:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // Do your ad thing here
    }
}

- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Second, create a storyboard and add your ad view controller to it. Then add an image view, a button, and a tap gesture recognizer to your view controller. The tap gesture recognizer should be dropped on the image view to capture taps from there. You pull all of these objects from the *Object Library* down right. Also remember to *enable user interaction* for the image view. There is a property for that on the property page.

You should now have something that looks like this:

[image: Storyboard for ad page]

Notice the class name top right which should be the name of your new view controller class you just created. Also notice the storyboard ID `adVC` which you need when instantiating the view controller from code.

The next step is to connect the objects. Select the image view, then drag from the outlet (the ring) under **Referencing Outlets** to the view controller icon (the yellow icon with a square in) located on top of the view controller window, and select `adImageView`. The gesture recognizer should already be connected, if you dropped it on the image view when you placed it previously.

[image: Connecting the image view]

Next, connect the action for the close button. Drag from the Touch Up Inside outlet to the view controller icon (the yellow one), and select the `closeButtonPressed:` method.

[image: Connecting the close button]

Next, connect the tap gesture recognizer to your code. Select it from the list on the left, then drag from **Sent Actions** to the view controller icon and select `tappedOnAd:`.

[image: Connecting the gesture recognizer]

Finally, your code to show the ad looks something like this. This method belongs in your parent view controller.

```
-(void)displayAd{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Thread
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullpageCampaign.mainImage]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AdPage" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"adVC"];
            [vc setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The approach that you described is standard and valid but my main approach on the architecture is I will create library and it will going to be static which developers will not see codes, gestures and UIView elements. With your suggestion, the project it has to be public and need to be implement some steps with storyboard.