# Getting a VC to appear inside another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 ViewControllers.

VC1 has a 2 views inside it.

I want to get MenuUIVC to appear in one of my views belonging(child) to VC1.

I tried this code inside of VC1 but it didn't work.

```
MenuUIVC * menuViewVC = [[MenuUIVC alloc] init];
menuUIView = menuViewVC.view;
```

I expected to be able to see the MenuUIVC inside the view (menuUIView) which is a child of VC1. I have the IBOutlets all hooked up on the storyboard.

Comment: Take a look on Container Views in iOS - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: Container view would be better option to add view controller as a subview controller.

Comment: You can implement this using container views. Check out https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/13/switching-child-view-controllers-ios-auto-layout/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding view controller as child view in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222383/adding-view-controller-as-child-view-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Container views to get View Controller inside a View Controller. And, you can get the reference to it through prepareForSegue() method.

[image: Container View]

**Links for description:**

1. [iOS Container View](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/)
2. [The Easy Way to Switch Container Views in iOS](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIView, then why don't you use

```
[menuUIView addSubview:menuViewVC.view];
```

Another option is to use childviewcontrollers.
See these links for example:-

1. [adding view controller as child view in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222383/adding-view-controller-as-child-view-in-ios)
2. [Add child view controller to current view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964884/add-child-view-controller-to-current-view-controller)

Using container or child view controller, gives you full fledge option of using View Controller properties, which you will not get in UIView.
Say for example, you can you orientation delegate methods, which you can't using in UIView class directly.
Hope this can help you.

Cheers
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

you can go for container view if you want to do it using IBOutlets & storyborad.
but if you want to do it using code then follow the below steps :

1. initialise & create parent view controller.
2. then add required child view as a subview with negative frame.
3. now change the frame with UIView animation whenever required. & do add tap gesture recogniser on part of screen other than the child view to remove it back to the initial position.